# How to generate zip file for a grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I wrote a Grails plugin, lets say PluginA which has dependency on another plugin, lets say PluginB, which I wrote myself too, these both plugins are being used by a main project. I am trying to build a continious integration system for this project using jenkins, so far I managed to setup everything in Jenkins. But while building the project, I get this error

```
Zip C:\Users\me\project\PluginA\grails-PluginA-0.1.zip is not a valid plugin
```

So, how do I generate that zip file, I noticed that all my other plugins have that zip file but I don't remember building them. I also tried to do a grails compile-plugin but I got an error saying that few classes were not found as they were in PluginB. So, how can I specify that PluginA has dependency on PluginB while running a grails command?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear, but I believe the problem you are having occurs when trying to build the main project and not the plugins, so I will address that situation.

Since the error message mentions a zip file, I will also assume you are using Grails 2.x.  If you are using Grails 3.x, then stop reading now and add info on how you are specifying your dependencies.

Key info: In my experience plugins don't come with their dependencies; I've had to re-declare them in my top-level projects.  I have no idea if that is the intent of the grails plugin design, but I have found it works to do so.

Step 1: Build PluginB and install it to your local maven repo using

```
grails maven-install
```

Step 2: Specify PluginB as a dependency for PluginA in its app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy

Step 3: Build PluginA and install it to your local maven repo using the same command as for PluginB.

Step 4: In your main project, specify dependencies on BOTH PluginA and PluginB in app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy

Step 4 is the key.

If I've misinterpreted your problem, sorry about that!  Please provide some more detail on exactly which part is failing and I'll let you know if I have any info on it.